# Leaflet Show all Markers from Database to Map

Tags: javascript, php

First I want to Demonstrate my code before asking my Question.

The code below will show all of my data from Database to my Webpage

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbmarker";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * from tblmarker";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo  "<br>",$row["lat"],"     &nbsp     &nbsp    &nbsp    &nbsp    &nbsp      ",$row["lng"] ;
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

and this is the output of my code that will show all of the Lat/Long

```
14.704659335030026           121.02397441864012
14.704659335030026           121.02397441864012
14.704659335030026           121.02397441864012
14.704659335030026           121.02397441864012
14.704659335030026           121.02397441864012
14.704659335030026           121.02397441864012
14.704659335030026           121.02397441864012
14.704659335030026           121.02397441864012
14.704659335030026           121.02397441864012
```

My question is how can i connect this output in this code?

```
var note = document.getElementById('note');
var datepick = document.getElementById('demo1');
var timepick = document.getElementById('timepick');
        layerpoly.on('click', function(e){
        var markerA = new L.Marker(e.latlng,{icon: Icon1});
        markerA.bindPopup("</a><br><strong>FIRE</strong></br><strong>Date:</strong>"+datepick.value+"</br><strong>Time:</strong>"+timepick.value+"</br><strong>Address:</strong>"+note.value+"<strong><br><strong>Suspect Sketch</strong><br><a href=legends/suspect.jpg rel=lightbox><img src = legends/suspect.jpg height=100 width = 100/>").addTo(map);
        closure1 (markerA)
```

Or to simplify my Question, How can i Fetch those outputs and convert them as Leaflet Lat/long of my marker? What will happen is that get the lat/long and put a marker on the map when the webpage finish load. TY

Answer (score 2):

you can create your array within the php data for examples:

```
$data = array();
    echo " var latlong = [ " ;

for ( $x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows( $query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query);
    echo " [ " , $data[ $x][ 'lat' ], " , " , $data[ $x][ 'long' ], " ] " ;
    if ( $x <= ( mysql_num_rows( $query) - 2) ) {
        echo " , " ;
    }
}
    echo " ]; " ;
```

This piece of code adjusted to your fields creates the var latlong and in your case gets the output of:

```
latlong = [
[14.704659335030026,121.02397441864012],
[14.704659335030026,121.02397441864012],
[14.704659335030026,121.02397441864012],
[14.704659335030026,121.02397441864012],
[14.704659335030026,121.02397441864012],
[14.704659335030026,121.02397441864012],
[14.704659335030026,121.02397441864012],
[14.704659335030026,121.02397441864012],
[14.704659335030026,121.02397441864012]];
```

Then you simply add your php into the map page like:

```
<?php include 'latlong.php' ?>
```

and a function for the points to be displayed like:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < latlong.length; i ++) {
marker = new L.marker([latlong[i][ 1 ],latlong[i][ 2]])
.addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: sir ahhhhm what i mean sir is that my program will get the lat/lng from my database and draw a marker in my map

Comment: Please see my edited post. I am just saying that you should format toy output in a way that the leaflet library can see it and then create a loop to add the markers on your map. Hope it helps.